# Execution failed for task app:processDebugMainManifest> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors --stacktrace option Run with --info or --debug

Tags: gradle, manifest, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get this stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

the answer of this error you just need to add the library in your gradle
gradle -> gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer of this error you just need to add the library in your gradle
gradle -> gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

**the answer of this error you just need to add the library in your gradle gradle -> gradle.properties**

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side, i got the same error, despite

> android.useAndroidX=true
>
> android.enableJetifier=true

In manifest.xml, the Activity was not exported

```
<activity
  android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
  android:exported="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34492879)